# Error of noSuchElement when using Java.util.scanner

Tags: java

The error occurs when I ask the user for their radius at `user_Radius.nextLine();` and I cannot find the problem at the moment because the `userName1.nextLine();` works just fine when I run the program.

**Error**

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line
>   found     at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)  at
>   CircleFormulas.main(scanner.java:22)

**My code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CircleFormulas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creates my constructors/variables
        //Scans for the user's name
        Scanner userName1 = new Scanner (System.in);
        //Scans for the radius the user wishes to calculate
        Scanner user_Radius = new Scanner (System.in);


        //Asks the user for their name and places their response into the userName variable
        System.out.println("What is your name?: ");
        String userName = userName1.nextLine();
        //closes the line function; locks the variable
        userName1.close();
        //Prints out a greeting for the user
        System.out.println("Hey " + userName + " How are you?");
        //Asks the user a question
        System.out.println("Now, what is the radius of the circle you'd like to calculate?");
        //Asks the user for their radius they'd like to calculate and places their response into the radius variable
        String radius = user_Radius.nextLine();
        user_Radius.close();
        //Prints out the radius of the user's circle
        System.out.println("So, the radius of your circle is: " + radius);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get your error because you try to reuse the `System.in` which is closed (even if it is declared in another variable, but is still closed).

You don't need to instantiate multiple scanners, it's enough to do it once and reuse it multiple times:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

String userName = scanner.nextLine();
String radius = scanner.nextLine();

scanner.close();
```